# How to stop it from automatically round off

Tags: java

This is my program

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double i2 = 17.123456;

        String latest = new DecimalFormat("##.#####").format(i2);

        System.out.println(latest);

    }
}
```

With this the output is 17.12346

But i need only 17.12345

I want to have only 5 digists after the decimal , But how can i stop it from automatic round off ??

Answer (score 2):

You can set the rounding mode: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#setRoundingMode(java.math.RoundingMode)

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("##.#####");
        format.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);
        System.out.println(format.format(17.123456d));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set rounding mode to DOWN

`java.lang.Enum.RoundingMode.DOWN`

Use setRoundingMode method on the DecimalFormat object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double i2 = 17.123456;
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#####");
        df= df.setScale(0, RoundingMode.DOWN);
        System.out.println(df.format(i2));
        }
}
```